# Payable function won't get executed (gas estimation fails)

Tags: solidity, remix, gas, gas-estimate, payable

Hey guys I am trying to create a function that would send Ether to a contract based on how many "USD" I put into an argument. But it keeps failing to estimate the gas and thus the transaction. I have enough testETH in my wallet for the information.

Can you please help me out? Thank you

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.17;

import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin- 
contracts/blob/master/contracts/security/ReentrancyGuard.sol";
import "https://github.com/NomicFoundation/hardhat/blob/main/packages/hardhatcore
/console.sol";
import 
"https://github.com/f22daniel/helpful_smart_contracts/blob/main/GoerliPriceFeed.sol";

contract SimpleExchange{
address priceFeedContract;
mapping(address => uint) public users;
mapping(address => uint) public timeStored;

constructor(){
    priceFeedContract = 0x3d1A8C94DC9Bcd78B1ADE1b4C678F26169041e77;
}

function EthUsd() public view returns(uint){
    if (GoerliPriceConsumerV3(priceFeedContract).getLatestEthPrice() < 0){
        return uint(-GoerliPriceConsumerV3(priceFeedContract).getLatestEthPrice());
        }
    else {
        return uint(GoerliPriceConsumerV3(priceFeedContract).getLatestEthPrice());
    }
}

function usdWeiConverter(uint _amount) public view returns(uint){
    uint priceEthUsd = EthUsd() * 10**10;
    uint amount = _amount * 10**18;
    uint ethAmountSent = (amount * 10**18)/priceEthUsd;
    return ethAmountSent;
}
function sendEthViaUsd(uint _amount) public payable{
    payable(address(this)).transfer(usdWeiConverter(_amount));
}
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how a contract works. You are using `payable` keyword in the function. That means it is expecting an `ETH` value. You cannot use `.transfer()` method and try to send the ETH to the contract. The function is doing it already.

And regarding your query, I don't think it can be done with a direct approach. The function will accept as many ETH as you send if you have not put in any checks. There can be two options that you can do:

1. Let the user send some amount of ETH to the function. Get the USD value from him too. Calculate the ETH amount equivalent to the USD he entered, keep those ETH and return the rest back. It will go something like this.

   ```
       function sendEthViaUsd(uint256 _amount) public payable {
          uint256 amount = msg.value;
          uint256 requiredAmount = usdWeiConverter(_amount);

          require(
            amount >= requiredAmount,
            "User needs to send higher ETH value."
          );
          payable(msg.sender).transfer(amount - requiredAmount);
       }
   ```
2. Take help from the front-end. They can calculate the ETH amount beforehand and can send the exact amount required.